# How do I setup EC2 instance Connect using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up EC2 Instance Connect for an EC2 instance:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Part 1 - Spawn Ec2 instance with CloudFormation

Resources:
  WebAppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      ImageId: ami-074cce78125f09d61
      InstanceType: t2.micro
```

Although the template above allows me to create an EC2 instance, it does not allow me to access it using EC2 Instance Connect.

[image]

How do I configure EC2 Instance Connect within the CloudFormation template?

**Solution**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Part 1 - Build a webapp stack with CloudFormation

Resources:
  WebAppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      ImageId: ami-074cce78125f09d61
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebAppSecurityGroup

  WebAppSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [webapp-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  WebAppEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      InstanceId: !Ref WebAppInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [webapp-eip, dev]]

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !Sub http://${WebAppEIP}
    Description: WebApp URL
```

Comment: Prevent users via IAM from creating SSH keys

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thats not the problem I am trying to address. The instances that I am creating with the template above does create an EC2 instance but it does not allow me to connect to it using EC2 Instance connect.

Comment: Ah OK - editing your question as it looked like you're trying to enforce EC2 instance connect (*"the only possible way to get ssh access to the machine should be via EC2 instance connect"*)

Comment: In addition to Marcin's answer, are you trying to connect via the UI? If so, your EC2 instance must have a public IPv4 address. Does it?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect using the UI and this is what I get. Evening opening the HTTPS traffic on port 22 does not help.

Comment: **But does it have a public IPv4 address?** I can probably say with 99% confidence that it doesn't - is that your entire CloudFormation template?

Comment: Setting a public ip fixed the issue to the problem

Comment: Added an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

On `Amazon Linux 2 (any version)` and `Ubuntu 16.04 or later` EC2 Instance Connect  is [installed and working](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) **by default**. So you don't have to do anything.

For other AMIs, you have to use user_data to [install and setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html)
the connect yourself.

Comment: I tried that but I am being redirected to the screen where there's an error stating "We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see Task 1: Configure network access to an instance."

Comment: @Salam If your security groups or VPC are incorrectly setup, instance connect will not work.

Comment: Setting the web security groups with a public ip4 address did the trick.

Comment: @Salam Glad it worked out. If any of the answer helped, acceptance of one of them is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure you have a public IP assigned.**

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ic-limitations):

> **To connect using the Amazon EC2 console (browser-based client)**, the instance must have a public IPv4 address.**

---

You can also
connect to the EC2 instance via other methods if you do not want to / cannot assign a public IPv4 address:

> If the instance does not have a public IP address, you can connect to the instance over a private network using an SSH client or the EC2 Instance Connect CLI. For example, you can connect from within the same VPC or through a VPN connection, transit gateway, or AWS Direct Connect.

---

*FYI: for other AMIs with Linux distributions other than Amazon Linux 2 or Ubuntu 16.04+, you will need extra configuration as Marcin's answer points out.*

*`ami-074cce78125f09d61` in `us-east-2` is coming up for me as `Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type` which supports EC2 Instance Connect by default, so your AMI should be fine.*